# Reassembler toolchain

Tags: windows, x86, c++, reassembly

I'm looking for tools to:

1. Disassemble a function from a x86 Windows executable into an asm file.
2. Edit the file.
3. Assemble the file again into an object file that can then be linked into a DLL.
4. Inject this DLL into the original target executable.

What disassembler and assembler combo allows me to do this ?

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2013 to inject C++ code which works fine but being able to edit the original assembly code without having to translate it to C++ first would be a nice improvement.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm currently using Visual Studio 2013 to inject C++ code which works
>   fine but being able to edit the original assembly code without having
>   to translate it to C++ first would be a nice improvement.

If you're using Visual Studio 2013, you don't need to translate the assembly code into C++. Just use [__asm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45yd4tzz.aspx).

Comment: Right, but I'd still need something to disassemble parts of the original binary into something that can be reassembled with __asm.

Comment: Your original question makes it sound like you already have the assembly code. You may want to reword your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Just FYI, the __asm feature does not work for 64-Bit projects; you need to create a separate .asm and compile with the MS macro-assembler.

Comment: It's about a x86 game (Red Alert 2), so that's not an issue.

Comment: It sounds like you'd be better off hooking the target function than going through the rigmarole you outlined above. Check out http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/

Comment: Hi Jason, I've already done that but it doesn't allow me to easily edit parts of the original function.

Answer (score 1):

disassembling the whole thing to something reassembleable is a huge feat, with high potential for errors if theres no reloc information or other things to 'assist' the disassembly.. i dont know of anything that will do this entirely.. there were old programs like sourcer etc in the dos days, but even then they got close, but not perfect.. what you're looking for i dont think exists.. yet

Comment: I'd like to do it one (or a few) functions at a time, not the whole executable at once.

Comment: hmm well the ida is probably good for that, i've done it myself, but it does require careful analysis of the code, the data blocks it access and other functions it calls.. i hope your target function is small :)